# Multiple select que compara duas listas do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, html-select

Preciso fazer um seletor múltiplo em HTML, sendo que a lista de itens será carregada de uma tabela MySQL usando PHP, entretanto, quero que os valores que já estão em outra tabela sejam preenchidos automaticamente.
No caso quando crio uma promoção, adiciono vários produtos, quando quero editar a promoção, gostaria que o select onde seleciono os produtos, mostrasse selecionado aqueles que já estão salvos.
Tentei alguns códigos mas não funciona, o mais perto é o atual que quando o primeiro item está selecionado, ele é marcado, mas os outros não.

```
$editDLL = "<br /><label>Itens</label><select name='itens[]' id='itens' class='form-control' multiple size='5'>";
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $selected = 0;
    $row3 = null;
    $id     = (int)$row2[0];
    $nome   = $row2[1];
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($cat2)) {
        $id2 = $row3[0];
        if ($id == $id2) {
            $selected = 1;
        }
    }
    if ($selected == 1) {
        $editDLL .= "<option value='$id' selected>$nome</option>";
        $selected = 0;
    } else {
        $editDLL .= "<option value='$id'>$nome</option>";
    }
}
$editDLL .= "</select>";
echo $editDLL;
```

Comment: Já pensou em um OUTER JOIN entre as tabelas?

Comment: não havia pensado, mas não sei se é a forma correta, já que preciso carregar todos os valores de uma tabela, mas marcar no html os que forem iguais a da outra tabela, de forma que todos os itens da tabela 1 estejam presentes no HTML

Comment: É o que se espera que um `SELECT * FROM tabela1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela2 ON (tabela1.campopk = tabela2.campofk)` faça.